# xtext/xtend use join to create list with multiple fields

Tags: xtext, xtend

I want to print an enum `enum State{A(0),B(1)}` as a comma seperated list, in the form `A=0, B=1`. For this xtext/xtend provides a join operation. However, I can't find any information on how to access multiple fields of the enum. The enum has a `toString` and `numVal` method.

E.g. `{«State::values.join(', ') [toString»=«numVal]»}` does not work. What is the correct syntax for such an operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your double colon "::" is a problem.

`println( State.values.join(', ')['''«toString»=«numVal»'''] )` works fine.

Or you can do it like this: `println( State.values.map['''«toString»=«numVal»'''].join(', ') )`

Both produce: `A=0, B=1`